# Show snapshots from camera Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I created a flex application that snapshot a picture of the webcam. Im trying now to save every snapshop and display it directly when the image has been capture. But I cant seems to understand how to.
I want the images to be display in the Thumbnail box.
 Any help ? or any sites I can found some help on ?

This is what I have for the moment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" verticalAlign="top"
                horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="0" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            private function videoDisplay_creationComplete() : void
            {
                var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();

                if (camera) 
                {
                    videoDisplay.attachCamera(camera);                    
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Alert.show("Oops, we can't find your camera.");
                }
            }

            private function capture_click() : void
            {
                var snap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(320, 240, true);
                var snapBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(snap);

                snapBmp.width = 320;
                snapBmp.height = 240;

                if(snapshotHolder.numChildren > 0)
                    snapshotHolder.removeChildAt(0);

                snapshotHolder.addChild(snapBmp);                
                snap.draw(videoDisplay);
            }
        ]]>

    </mx:Script>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Panel title="Video">
            <mx:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" creationComplete="videoDisplay_creationComplete();" width="320" height="240" />        
        </mx:Panel>

        <mx:Panel title="Snapshot">
            <mx:UIComponent id="snapshotHolder" width="320" height="240" />
        </mx:Panel>

    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Button label="reload camera" click="videoDisplay_creationComplete();"/>
        <mx:Button label="capture" click="capture_click();"/>    
    </mx:HBox>

    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Panel title="Thumbnails">
        <mx:UIComponent id="snapshotHolderTN" width="128" height="96" />
        </mx:Panel>
    </mx:HBox>


</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls try with this when u click for image snaps.

```
     var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videodisplay.width,videodisplay.height);
     bmp.draw(drawArea);

     var jpgEncode:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(50);
     var imageByte:ByteArray = jpgEncode.encode(bmp);


     var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference;
     fileRef.save(imageByte);
```